# Transactions not starting on JSF @ViewScoped @Stateless bean

Tags: jsf-2, transactions, ejb-3.0, cdi, stateless-session-bean

I have a JSF 2 `@ViewScoped` based webapp, that I cannot get the transactions to go with correctly, or rather: **they don't start at all**.

I'm using Java EE 6's CDI and EJB3, too.

Here's the main bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
...

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@Stateless
public class PqManager implements Serializable
{
    private List<PqListItem> pqItems;

    @Inject
    private PqService pqService;

    public List<PqListItem> getPqItems()
    {
        if ( pqItems == null )
        {
            pqItems = pqService.findActivePqs();
        }

        return pqItems;
    }

    ...
}
```

The view-scoped bean is used from a JSF page to display a simple list in a datatable. It was made view-scoped because it has AJAX-based operations to add items, remove items, and to sort them via RichFaces (filtering).

I added `@Stateless` for every method invocation to start a transaction (or create a new one if none exists, the default is `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED`). This idea was taken from the book 'Core JavaServer Faces, 3rd ed.', however I haven't found any examples that would match my own.

Injected PqService class (it doesn't make a difference to use `@EJB` instead):

```
@Stateless
public class PqService extends JpaCrudService
{
    ...

    public List<PqListItem> findActivePqs()
    {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT NEW ... whatever not interesting here... WHERE pq.workflow = '" + Workflow.ACTIVE + "' GROUP BY pq.id", PqListItem.class).getResultList();
    }

    ...
}
```

JpaCrudService (basically taken from Adam Bien's example http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/generic_crud_service_aka_dao):

```
//@Stateless
//@Local(CrudService.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public abstract class JpaCrudService implements CrudService
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PqGeneratorPu")
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public <T> T create(T t)
    {
        em.persist(t);
        em.flush();
        em.refresh(t);

        return t;
    }

    ...
}
```

The only difference is that I subclass `JpaCrudService` because I don't like queries stored in/at the entities. So I omitted the `@Local` annotation (correct me if that's wrong). `@Stateless` isn't inherited AFAIK and I only inject the subclasses so I also commented that one out.

That said, the bean is then accessed from a JSF page:

```
  <rich:dataTable value="#{pqManager.pqItems}"
                  var="pq">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Active" />
    </f:facet>
    ...
```

However, when loading the page, I get an exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRequiredException: Transaction is required for invocation: org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext@7a6c1c92
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.mandatory(CMTTxInterceptor.java:255)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72)
    at de.company.webapp.service.PqService$$$view95.findActivePqsFor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:111)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
    at de.company.webapp.service.PqService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.findActivePqs(PqService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
    at de.company.webapp.facade.PqManager.getPqItems(PqManager.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    .
    .
    .
```

It fails because the call `pqService.findActivePqsFor()` doesn't run in an existing transaction (`TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY`, which **is** inherited AFAIK).

Note, that the page is displayed correctly without using transactions by deleting the `TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY` on the `JpaCrudService` and using an extended entity manager, but this was just for testing purposes.

But why isn't this working? Why isn't the transaction started here? Is there anything with the JSF `@ViewScoped` bean? Incompatible?

**How do you repair this?**

PS: I'm using JBoss AS 7.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of you're using CDI drop the JSF annotations. JSF annotations don't control EJBs the way CDI will. You're probably confusing the container with the annotations being used. You could also use MyFaces CODI for some extensions or look at recreating the ViewScope with CDI. There are a few examples online.

Comment: Thanks. Is Seam 3 Faces the/a solution I'm looking for? I finally wonder what other people do to get transaction from such a @ViewScoped bean in plain Java EE 6 without CDI. How would that work/look like?

Comment: Yes, it would work, however, Seam 3 is not being actively developed. Work is going into DeltaSpike, but we haven't addressed JSF yet. As for the other question, you would do a JNDI lookup for the UserTransaction and manually handle the transaction boundaries.

Comment: Well, for now I just need a solution that would start the transactions **at all**. I'll keep an eye or two on DeltaSpike, see http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/04/seam-deltaspike. Thanks for this top info!